# OpenCL 2D Array Implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, parallel-processing, opencl

Currently working on a 2D array implementation with OpenCL. For the most part this all works out just fine when matrix_size is less about 15 or less. When I increase it to something like 100 the program crashes. According to the visual studio debugger the issue appears to be integer division by 0. I'm not quite sure where that could be occurring.
My assumption: this is an issue with work-item and work-group:

```
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(matrix_size*matrix_size), cl::NullRange);
```

Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how to go about resolving this. Ultimately I want to be able to run these basic calculations on relatively large datasets.

```
int main() {
`   srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    const int matrix_size = 100;
    string input;
    string func;
    string input_file;
    cout << "Please enter a arithmetic option: multi or add" << endl;
    cout << ">> ";
    input_file = "MatrixArithmetic.cl";
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input[0] == 'a') {func = "matrix_add";}
    else if (input[0] == 'm') {func = "matrix_multi";}
    else { cout << "Not a valid option... exiting" << endl; return 0; }
    ifstream ArithmeticFile(input_file);
    string src(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ArithmeticFile), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));


    //prepare platform
    vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    auto platform = platforms.front();
    //gather device info from platform and store into devices vector
    vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
    //chose device for computation
    auto device = devices.front();
    cout << "Using device: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << endl;
    /*cout << "This: " << CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "This 2: " << CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE << endl;*/
    //setup the context

    cl::Program::Sources sources;
    sources.push_back({ src.c_str(), src.length() });
    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::Program program(context, sources);
    auto err = program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");
    //setup kernel (this is kernel specific)
    cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float)*matrix_size*matrix_size);
    cl::Buffer buffer_B(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float)*matrix_size*matrix_size);
    cl::Buffer buffer_C(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float)*matrix_size*matrix_size);
    //build and seed matrix using random for computation this is done on the main processor
    float vec1[matrix_size][matrix_size];
    float vec2[matrix_size][matrix_size];
    for (int x = 0; x < matrix_size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix_size; y++) {
            vec1[x][y] = (float)(1+rand()%(rand()%1000));
            vec2[x][y] = (float)(1+rand()%(rand()%1000));
        }
    }
    //queue setup for pushing commands to device
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);
    //write vec1 and vec2 to device
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*matrix_size*matrix_size, vec1);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*matrix_size*matrix_size, vec2);
    ////run the kernel
    cl::Kernel kernel = cl::Kernel(program, func.c_str());
    //pushing argument to kernel it has 3 total arguments
    kernel.setArg(0, buffer_A);
    kernel.setArg(1, buffer_B);
    kernel.setArg(2, buffer_C);
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(matrix_size*matrix_size), cl::NullRange);
    queue.finish();
    //writing to the buffer 
    float vec3[matrix_size][matrix_size];
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*matrix_size*matrix_size, vec3);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}


Kernel:

    __kernel void matrix_add(__global const float *A, __global float *B, 

    __global float *C)
    {
        //index of the current element
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        //operation
        C[x] = A[x] + B[x];
    }

    __kernel void matrix_multi(__global const float *A, __global const float *B, __global float *C)
    {
        //OpenCL does not take 2D arrays it had to be flatten
        //index of the current element
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        //operation
        C[x] = A[x] * B[x];
}
```

Specs: i5 4690K and AMD r9 290 8GB Ram. So memory should not be an issue each "Matrix" should take up about than 4000 bytes at a size of 100x100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprits:
rand()%1000 evaluated to 0 on occasion.

```
vec1[x][y] = (float)(1+rand()%(1+rand()%1000));
vec2[x][y] = (float)(1+rand()%(1+rand()%1000));
```

Change to:

```
vec1[x][y] = (float)(1+rand()%(1+rand()%1000));
vec2[x][y] = (float)(1+rand()%(1+rand()%1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat a 1-D array(or allocation) as an 2-D array using a wrapper:

```
MDArr buf = new MDArr(100,100); // allocates 10k memory and gets its pointer
buf[10][90]=3; // this is overloaded operator usage for host-side
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(.,..,buf.ptr()) // 0th addreess of contiguous mem
                                    // same as &vec1[0][0]
```

so it doesn't access to non-contiguous prohibited areas.

Edit: 100x100 float array must be 4*100*100 = 40k memory area for x86 cpu